# Boostrap Tabs with Angular js

Tags: angularjs, tabs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using a tabset and sets of different tabs of angular ui bootstrap.

I would like to move in a click to some tab. 
Moreover, i would like to know which of the tabs is opened right now.

I created a variable in service called currentTab.

The idea is when i am clicking in a tab, the current tab is updated. 
I can move between the tabs , however, i got an error message in console:   "Expression '{0}' used with directive '{1}' is non-assignable!"

Moreover, I have to draw every tab different.

Any ideas?

```
 <tabset>
    <tab active="currentService.isCurrentTabEqualsGivenName('tab1')" ng-click="currentService.setCurrentTab('tab1')">
        <tab-heading><span class="badge">3</span>  <span>Tab 1</span>
        </tab-heading>

          SOMETHING
    </tab>
     <tab active="currentService.isCurrentTabEqualsGivenName('tab2')" ng-click="currentService.setCurrentTab('tab2')">
        <tab-heading>Tab 2</tab-heading>
          SOMETHING
         </tab>
 </tabset>
```

CurrentService:

```
 app.service('CurrentService', [
              function () {

 this.currentTab = "tab1";

 this.isCurrentTabEqualsGivenName = function(name){
        return this.currentTab === name;
    };

    this.setCurrentTab = function(name){
        if (this.currentTab !== name)
            this.currentTab = name;
    };
 }]);
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a know issue for the Angular UI team and the community, look at https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/611 for the full discussion.

The solution that worked for me was the one provided by @gilluminate, at https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/611#issuecomment-70339233

I post it here for full reference:

```
<button class="btn" ng-click="activateTab('search')">Search</button>
<button class="btn" ng-click="activateTab('preview')">Preview</button>
<button class="btn" ng-click="activateTab('edit')">Edit</button>

<tab heading="Search" active="active.search">...</tab>
<tab heading="Preview" active="active.preview">...</tab>
<tab heading="Edit" active="active.edit">...</tab>
```

then set up your default tab like so:

```
$scope.active = {
  search: true
};
```

and the `activateTab()` function:

```
$scope.activateTab = function(tab) {
  $scope.active = {}; //reset
  $scope.active[tab] = true;
}
```

Comment: active attribute value / variable should be a assignable.